# Fastest way or alternative way of counting elements in a enumerable of custom type in C#

Tags: c#, enumerable, except

I am doing an except of two DataTables in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23). I've overloaded the IEqualityComparer

```
public bool Equals(T sourceRec, T targetRec)
    {
        string srcHash, tgtHash;
        srcHash = HashGenerator.GenerateHash<T>(sourceRec);
        tgtHash = HashGenerator.GenerateHash<T>(targetRec);
        return srcHash.Equals(tgtHash);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
```

and except will work by taking into consideration of the Hash value of each DataRow.

```
public class CompareResult<T>
    {
        public IEnumerable<T> Inserted_Updated;
        public IEnumerable<T> Updated;
        public IEnumerable<T> Deleted;
    }

 public CompareResult<DataRow> Compare(DataTable source, DataTable target)
        {
            CompareResult<DataRow> rest = new CompareResult<DataRow>();
            rest.Inserted_Updated = target.AsEnumerable().Except(source.AsEnumerable(), RowHashComparer);
            rest.Deleted = (source.AsEnumerable().Except(target.AsEnumerable(), RowHashComparer)).Except(target.AsEnumerable().Except(source.AsEnumerable(), RowHashComparer));

            return rest;
        }

CompareResult<DataRow> strResult = SD1.Compare(src, tgt);
```

RowHashComparer is as a property used to perform custom except by comparing Hash codes.
What i tracked down is the equality comparison is actually happening after the Except method has returned.

Please suggest.

Comment: Instead of returning an `Enumerable`, you could return a `HashSet<>`.

Comment: I have a bag full of marbles, I want to know how many marbles I have. Can you tell me a way that doesn't involve *counting* them one by one? Well, no, not really. Maybe you should take a step back and ask yourself if a bag is what you really need. Does some other type of collection do a better job?

Comment: @InBetween - money can be counted by weighting it.  Standardized marbles in a bag with a known weight can be counted with a scale.

Comment: @Moho exactly, but then its not an `Enumerable` any more. You need additional tools, the bag by itself is not enough.

Comment: Can you paste the code of your overload? Maybe you can do some administration there.

Comment: @Vineet Alampally Please share your code so i can work out.

Comment: @RohitPoudel

I've improved the question, please have a look.

Comment: @brijber please have a look at the improved question

Comment: If you're using a `DataTable` why not just do `table.Where(row => row.RowState == DataRowState.Added || row.RowState == DataRowState.Modified);`?

Comment: @brijber i have to bring out the set difference between two tables.

Comment: @Vineet Alampally cant we convert datatable to List

Comment: @RohitPoudel yes, we can. But ToList() takes a lot of time. My dataset is huge one.

Comment: @Vineet Alampally    If you're using .NET 3.5, you can use you can use `DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable`(an extension method) and then if you really need a `List<DataRow>` instead of just `IEnumerable<DataRow>' you can call 'Enumerable.ToList:` `IEnumerable<DataRow> sequence = dt.AsEnumerable(); `                  
 or

`using System.Linq;`
...
`List<DataRow> list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();`

Comment: @RohitPoudel I have tried that already, Enumerable.ToList() is taking a lot of time. My datatable has around 200K rows.

Comment: @RohitPoudel I've tracked down the problem, realized that the problem is something else. I've improved the question. Please have a look and suggest.

Comment: @brijber I've tracked down the problem, realized that the problem is something else. I've improved the question. Please have a look and suggest.

Comment: @Vineet Alampally better if we can do this on stored procedure if possible

Answer (score -3):

The simplest form would be:

```
public static int Count(this IEnumerable source)
{
    int c = 0;
    using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (e.MoveNext())
            c++;
    }
    return c;
}
```

we can then improve on this by querying for `ICollection`:

```
public static int Count(this IEnumerable source)
{
    var col = source as ICollection;
    if (col != null)
        return col.Count;

    int c = 0;
    using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (e.MoveNext())
            c++;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: And this improves `Enumerable.Count<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)` exactly how?

Comment: @Rohit - check out the latest syntactical sugar in C#: 
    if( source is ICollection col )
    {
        return col.Count;
    }

Comment: @Moho Thank you for suggestion.. i am working on it.

Comment: How does this differ from [Microsoft implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,fd1d89b855e431da)?